# Inequality in functional analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a little question about functional analysis, limit and inequality.

> Let a function $f$ with domain $]0,+\infty[$ and codomain $]0,+\infty[$ and twice differentiable with the following inequality :
>   $$f'+f''\geq f^2$$
>
> Show that the limits of $f$ when $x$ tends to infinity exists and determine it.

**My try :**

> I make the following substition :
>   $$f(x)=-g(-e^{-x})$$
>   And the inequality becomes :
>   $$g(-e^{-x})^2\leq e^{-2x}(-g''(-e^{-x}))$$
>   Or 
>   $$g(X)^2\leq X^2(-g''(X))$$
>   if we put $X=-e^{-x}$

After that, I think we can use a Wirtinger-like type inequality (perhaps generalized) but I don't know how.

If you can read in french see [here.](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/posting.php?4,edit,1513504)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, if "Malheureusement " means "unfortunately" (don't you laugh, anybody, the spanish "desafortunadamente" isn't any better), I can read that snippet, but it doesn't add much information. May I ask why you think that may be important?

Comment: @Professor Vector "Mathematics, rightly viewed, possesses not only truth, but supreme beauty "Bertrand Russell.So it's important for me...and maybe for you :)

Comment: Ok, that's enough info (not only) for me. Good luck!

Comment: @Professor Vector my snippet was a mystake (I realize this just now) .The reals informations are [here](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?4,1513278,page=2).

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution.  If $f(x)$ has a finite limit $L$ as $x\to\infty$, then $L=0$.  For $f'(x)+f''(x) = e^{-x} (d/dx) \,(\exp(x)f'(x)).$  Integrating the inequality $f'+f''\ge f^2$ we get $$e^xf'(x) - e^1 f'(1) \ge \int_1^x e^t f^2(t)\,dt$$ and
$$ f'(x)\ge e^{1-x}f'(1) + \int_1^x e^{t-x} f^2(t)\,dt.$$  If $f$ has limit $L$, the right hand side is, for all $x$ sufficiently large, greater than $L^2/2$.  Hence $f(x)\ge A + (L^2/2) x$ for all $x$ sufficiently large, which is possible only if $L=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x)\le 0$ for all $x>0$, then $f$ is decreasing and so it has a limit $L\in [0,\infty)$ as $x\to\infty$. As in the proof of kimchi lover, necessarily, $L=0$.

It remains to study the case in which $f'(x_0)> 0$ for some $x_0>0$. But then, again as in the proof of kimchi lover (with $1$ replaced by $x_0$) we get 
$$f'(x)\ge e^{x_0-x}f'(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x e^{t-x} f^2(t)\,dt>0,$$ which shows that $f$ is strictly increasing, and so it has a limit $L\in [0,\infty]$ as $x\to\infty$. But since $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, necessarily $f(x)\ge f(x_0)>0$ for all $x>x_0$ and so $L\ge f(x_0)>0$. If $L$ were finite then $L=0$ as in the proof of kimchi lover, which is a contradiction. Thus $L=\infty$.

Comment: Have you an example of function wich tends to infinity when $x$ tends to infinity ?

Comment: no I don't. It cannot go to infinity as a power or as $e^x$. I actually think that if $f'(x_0)>0$ then the solution will explode in finite time, but I don't see an easy way to prove it.